# SQL: How to dynamically calculate a value from a separate table?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I'm building a Hacker News-style page, and I'm trying to get a list of posts from the database to display on the page, including data as to whether or not the current user has voted on a particular post.

I'm trying to query a list of `posts` (from the `posts` table), and I want to perform a join on the `votes` table (post.id on votes.postId) to see if a given post has been voted on by the current user, and return something like `userHasVoted` for each post that comes back, calculated on the fly.

I've been trying to make this happen, but only seem to return the posts the user has voted for.

How can I query the DB to show every post and whether or not it was voted on by a given user?

Here is my votes table:

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| id | userId | postId | value |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |     1 |
|  2 |      2 |      1 |     1 |
|  3 |      4 |      3 |     1 |
|  4 |      1 |      5 |     0 |
|  5 |      3 |      2 |     1 |
|  6 |      4 |      8 |     1 |
|  7 |      1 |      8 |     1 |
|  8 |      4 |      9 |     1 |
|  9 |      1 |      9 |     1 |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
```

And here's my posts table (leaving out title, content, link, etc):

```
+----+---------------+--------+
| id | publishStatus |authorId|
+----+---------------+--------+
|  1 | PUBLIC        |      1 |
|  2 | PUBLIC        |      2 |
|  3 | PUBLIC        |      3 |
|  4 | PUBLIC        |      4 |
|  5 | PUBLIC        |      2 |
|  6 | PUBLIC        |      1 |
|  7 | PUBLIC        |      1 |
|  8 | PUBLIC        |      1 |
|  9 | PUBLIC        |      1 |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: So a user can vote repeatedly for the same post? (If not, why does your votes table have an `id` column?)

Comment: Not sure I understand you @melpomene - the votes `id` column is just to track each vote in the db. Technically the users can remove their vote - not sure if that clears it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example where you could get `Yes` or `No` instead of `1` or `0`

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, CASE 
        WHEN v.value = 0
            THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
        END userHasVoted
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN votes v ON p.id = v.postid
```

[image]

Comment: Ah @Brien , but v.userHasVoted doesn't exist in any row of the `votes` table - that's what I want to calculate on the fly...

Comment: Please post your table definitions and some example data.

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Comment: Ah- but this gives me duplicate posts for each vote out there anyone has cast; I'm trying to get the list of posts without that duplication...

Comment: @S.McGraw Updated answer to use DISTINCT. If this isn't what you want, I need to see a few rows of exactly what you expect to see, like one or two rows of exactly how you want the output to be.

Answer (score -2):

### *select a.name as post_name,sum(vote.value) count_of_votes from post a *join* vote on a.id=vote.postid group by name*

----------------------------**-for finding total votes from all users for particular post**